# Converting an entire column from Uni Time (Epoch) to a human readable timestamp in Snowflake. Strange results

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I used this code:

```
SELECT dateadd(S, START_EPOCH, '19700101')
```

1639075874000 got converted into 53910-11-15 14:08:21.000

Anyone know what I've done wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `1639075874000`  is a number of milisecods, thus division by 1000 is required:

```
SELECT dateadd(second, START_EPOCH/1000, '1970-01-01'::TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This solved it. The project guide stated that it was in seconds but I guess it was a mistake on their part.